# Access to fetch at "api" from origin localhost is blocked by cors

Tags: web3.js

I am failing to connect to solana blockchain, devnet, testnet and sometimes even projectSerum

The way i connect is straightforward:

```
const connection = new solana.Connection(theapi as string,'confirmed');
```

Found a similar issue here: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/26341

Any ideas how to avoid this, or some (testnet/devnet) api that works?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it ended up being a configuration bug that has since been fixed. More details here: github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/26341